# gradle install is slower than maven install?

Tags: performance, maven, gradle

I have big JAVA system (java 8) which includes more than 50 projects/modules. It was using maven install (Apache Maven 3.6.3). I migrate it to gradle install (version 6.5.1) as follows + manually add all maven transitive dependency to build.gradle of every module:

```
> gradle init
```

To compare the install performance, the following was executed for gradle install:

```
gradle install -x test --parallel
```

and for maven install:

```
 mvn clean install -T4C -DskipTests -U
```

To my surprise, maven is almost 2 times faster than gradle. Perhaps adding duplicate dependency on each project makes install expensive. But I can't skip adding them repeatedly. Do I do something wrong here? Or (gradle seems having promise of better performance). How can I improve the performance of gradle install? Thank you.

Comment: A small hint the `-U` is not needed except you have external SNAPSHOT dependencies. Further question: Do you really need to `install`?

Comment: provoking question: Why migrating to Gradle if Maven is faster? (I'm biased)...

Answer (score 1):

The Gradle task `install` is part of the **deprecated** Gradle Maven plugin (`maven`). You should use the modern Gradle Maven Publish plugin (`maven-publish`) and its task `publishToMavenLocal`.

Gradle is optimized for subsequent builds. It provides enhanced up-to-date checking which ensures that only the parts of your software are build that changed since the last build. It also uses a daemon process that runs in the background waiting for new builds to reduce the startup time of subsequent builds. This feature however increases the startup time of the first build, so it should be disabled whenever just one build should be run on a machine (e.g. in CI).